# Image Re positioning in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I want to set the axis of a image inside div on the time of dragging.
for this I am using jquery ui: draggable function. But its behavior is not according to requirement.

```
<div id="photo_container">
<img id="profile_pic" 
src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ERPa9-zC-N8/UIkwNj_4JoI/AAAAAAAAAE4/akX3NIBh_Sw/s1600/cartoon_wallpaper.jpg"/>
```

> **Look at Live example for whole code**

In above html, height of div is less than `<img>` so when I try to drag and re position the image. it jumped to the start or end point.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dhaliwaljee/U5nCB/9/)

I have googling but I didn't find any good answer. Anybody here can help me, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "set the axis" exactly? Do you want to get location in the picture where the user started to drag?

Comment: Look at the Live example, 'y' axis is 0px and 'x' is auto, but when I drag down side it jumped to -250px, I want to move it in slow order like 
0px
-10px
-20px
.
.
.
.
.
-250px

it should not be jumped.

Comment: `I have googling`, they've _binging_ and _yahooing_ too. Did you try them?

Answer (score 1):

Add for the `photo_container` selector position relative, and the img `profile_pic` will be positionoed by absolute. I think this solution what you want

Comment: i've made a fiddle for you, because this need to be the right way

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but your image is dragging under the document, But I want to drag under the div. you can see there image in dragging downward more than div's height.